# Buenas, busco saber como tomar ciertos valores de un array (Mayores a 20 en este caso) y colocarlos dentro de otro y luego mostrar ese array, gracias

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Esto es en lo que estaría estancado

```js
$("#btnGuardar").click(Guardar);
$("#btnMostrar").click(Mostrar);

let arrayNumerico = [];

function Guardar() {
    var dato = Number($("#lblNumero").val());
    arrayNumerico.push(dato);

    console.log(arrayNumerico)
}   

function Mostrar(arrayNumerico) {
    let arrayMayor20 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayNumerico.length; i++) {
        arrayMayor20[i] == arrayNumerico
        if (dato > 20) {
            arrayMayor20.push(dato)
        }
    }
    $("#pParrafo").html(arrayMayor20);
    console.log(arrayMayor20)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable `dato` no existe... y por lo que entiendo debería ser igual a `arrayNumerico[i]`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$("#btnGuardar").click(Guardar);
$("#btnMostrar").click(Mostrar);

let arrayNumerico = [];

function Guardar() {
  var dato = Number($("#lblNumero").val());
  arrayNumerico.push(dato);
  console.log(arrayNumerico)
}

function Mostrar(arrayNumerico) {
  let arrayMayor20 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayNumerico.length; i++) {
    let dato = arrayNumerico[i] // <- ACA
    if (dato > 20) {
      arrayMayor20.push(dato)
    }
  }
  $("#pParrafo").html(arrayMayor20);
  console.log(arrayMayor20)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para filtrar los datos de un array puedes usar el método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

El método filter recibe una función a la que se le va pasando cada elemento del array. La función debe devolver `true` si un elemento cumple la condición y `false` si no. El resultado se devuelve y puedes almacenar el array resultante en una variable nueva.

Ej:

```js
const numeros = [ 10, 13, 3, 45, -23, -2, 0 ];

const menoresDe10 = numeros.filter(numero => {
  return numero < 10;
});
console.log(`Menores de 10: ${menoresDe10}`);

const menoresDe0 = numeros.filter(numero => {
  return numero < 0;
});
console.log(`Menores de 0: ${menoresDe0}`);

const mayoresDe5 = numeros.filter(numero => {
  return numero > 5;
});
console.log(`Mayores de 5: ${mayoresDe5}`);
```

Espero que esto te ayude a encontrar la respuesta que necesitas.